# Fallo Array PHP

Tags: php, array

Fallo en la primera linea del array, alguien puede decirme cual es el error?

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting
>   ']'

```
  $DAW [
'Sistemas informaticos'=>$horas['plazas'=>30,'horas'=>100],
'Bases de datos'=>$horas['plazas'=>30,'horas'=>100],
'Programacion'=>$horas['plazas'=>30,'horas'=>100],
'Entornos de desarollo'=>$horas['plazas'=>30,'horas'=>100],
'Lenguaje de marcas'=>$horas['plazas'=>30,'horas'=>100],
'Formacion y orientacion laboral'=>$horas['plazas'=>30,'horas'=>100],
'Diseño de interfaces web'=>$horas['plazas'=>30,'horas'=>100],
'Despliegue aplicaciones web'=>$horas['plazas'=>30,'horas'=>100],
'Desarrollo web en entorno cliente'=>$horas['plazas'=>30,'horas'=>100],
'Desarrollo web entono Servidor'=>$horas['plazas'=>30,'horas'=>100],
'Empresa e iniciativa empremsdedora'=>$horas['plazas'=>30,'horas'=>100],
'Formacion en centros de trabajo'=>$horas['plazas'=>30,'horas'=>100],
'Proyecto'=>$horas['plazas'=>30,'horas'=>100]
],
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que quitarle el $horas a todos

```
'Sistemas informaticos'=>$horas['plazas'=>30,'horas'=>100],
```

Cámbialo por

```
'Sistemas informaticos'=>['plazas'=>30,'horas'=>100],
```

O bien si es un arreglo del que quieres obtener un indice quedaría así

```
'Sistemas informaticos'=>$horas['nombre_de_tu_indice'],
```

Esto para todos en el arreglo

Comment: gracias...pero sigue dando el mismo error :(

Comment: También te falta igualar la variable  $DAW [ .. en vez de eso pon $DAW = [ ..

Comment: @JackNavaRow no necesariamente ambas son formas válidas de array en php y ambas tienen los mismo valores

Answer (score 0):

Tu error es de Logica.tienes dos opciones para declarar bien tu arreglo

**Opcion 1**

```
$DAW = array('Sistemas informaticos'=>array('plazas'=>30,'horas'=>100));
```

**Opcion 2**

```
$DAW = array('Sistemas informaticos'=>['plazas'=>30,'horas'=>100]);
```